# Firebase & Google map - read datas and create markers. How to read object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an application which consist in bulky wastes' signalements where each citizen could inform authorities about the place to collect them.

Datas (addresses and coordinates) are stocked into firebase and I'm working on the display of markers in a google map.

Here is the code:

```
 jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    markers: findMarkers();

    console.log(markers);
    console.log(markers.length);

    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +  
        '<p>' + 'adresse' +'</p>' +        '</div>'],
    ]; 

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1].lat(), markers[i][1].lng());
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(14);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });    
}
function findMarkers(){

  markers = [];

  var data = firebase.database();

  var dataRef = firebase.database().ref("signalement/");
   dataRef.on("child_added", function(data) {
        var key = data.key;
        const signalement = data.val();
        const adresse = signalement.adresse;
        const coordonnees = signalement.coordonnees;
        var marker = [adresse, coordonnees];
        markers.push( marker );
  });

   // Multiple Markers
   return markers;

}

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="map_wrapper">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
</div>
 </html>
```

Problem comes from the `console.log(markers.length);` which is equal to 0 ! While the previous `console.log(markers);` shows the object.

Maybe a syntax error of var marker?
Anyway.
Someone to help me for this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with the firebase data callback. Since you have set the callback for google map api `callback=initialize` the marker data is not ready from the firebase by the time it executes the function.

I would rather do something like this (keeping in mind that firebase callback takes longer than the google map script being loaded & map has dependency on the data from firebase).

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=findMarkers";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize(markers) {
   var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

   // Display a map on the page
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
   map.setTilt(45);

   console.log(markers);
   console.log(markers.length);

   // Info Window Content
   var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +  
        '<p>' + 'adresse' +'</p>' +        '</div>'],
    ]; 

// Display multiple markers on a map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1].lat(), markers[i][1].lng());
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(14);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});    
}

function findMarkers(){

    markers = [];

    var data = firebase.database();

    var dataRef = firebase.database().ref("signalement/");
    dataRef.on("child_added", function(data) {
        var key = data.key;
        const signalement = data.val();
        const adresse = signalement.adresse;
        const coordonnees = signalement.coordonnees;
        var marker = [adresse, coordonnees];
        markers.push( marker );
    });

   // send prepared marker array to map initialize function
    intialize(markers);
}
```